# Get nosetests attr for currently running test

Tags: python, nose

How can I get the current set of `@attr`-defined attributes for the currently running test case under nosetests?

---

I have tests that are partitioned into two groups:

- Those that expect a certain set of data to have been pre-loaded into the DB and are read-only regarding that data
- Those that are destructive and wipe that data and reload other new data

Loading the static set of data is rather expensive, and so isn't feasible to do per-test.

I have some utility functions that are used by the destructive tests, but occasionally a developer forgets to tag the test in question with `@attr('destructive')` and so the test works fine locally, but fails when run as part of the larger group (because it gets slotted into the middle of the non-destructive tests, so all of the later tests fail).

I would like to be able to verify that the destructive attribute has been set inside of those utility functions so that the test will fail in dev if the test function hasn't been properly tagged.

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34618095/is-there-a-way-for-a-python-nose-test-to-know-its-decorated-attributes/34626292 answer your question?

Comment: It links to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20894584/read-nose-tests-arguments-in-a-file-especially-attr/20908432#20908432 which suggests `getattr(cls, sys._getframe().f_back.f_code.co_name).__dict__` but that only works if you know the call stack depth that the utility function gets called at. I was hoping for something a little less awful than walking back up the call stack, looking at the called functions as I go.